# Mapping device input event codes to new event codes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, events, io

I am currently trying to restore an old arcade machine, and I'm running into issues with interpreting the events from the usb controller. In particular, the controller is sending the event code `1:300` (`EV_KEY:300`), but unfortunately 300 is not a valid event code. Because of this, I am unable to get it to work with the arcade software that I am using.

What I'm looking to do is run a process that intercepts the `1:300` events and turns them into some other type of event. For example, every time I press the joystick, I may want it to be interpreted as `1:194` (`EV_KEY:KEY_F24`).

Any idea how to do this?

Output from `evtest`:

```
Event: time 1669313468.400824, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9000d
Event: time 1669313468.400824, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 300 (?), value 0
```

I've tried various input mapping softwares such as `evsieve`, but to no avail.

Output from `evsieve`:

```
While parsing the arguments "--map key:300 key:up":
    While parsing the key "key:300":
        Invalid argument: unknown event code "300".
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I at least found a temporary workaround:

```
CONTROLLER1_LOCATION=/dev/input/by-id/usb-GGG_GPWiz49-event-joystick
CONTROLLER1_EVENT_PORT=event6
BTN=BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY4

sudo /bin/evtest $CONTROLLER1_LOCATION EV_KEY 300 \
        | grep "300.*value" --line-buffered \
        | grep --line-buffered -o "[01]$" \
        | while read x ; do sudo evemu-event /dev/input/$CONTROLLER1_EVENT_PORT --type EV_KEY --code $BTN --value $x ; done
```

Basically this:

1. Monitors the device for matching erroneous events
2. Takes the output that corresponds to actual button presses
3. And sends a virtual event from the controller

This could definitely be cleaned up, but it'll do for now